# mongoose put method is working as a post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created this web API using mongoose.

POST and GET work fine, but mongoose seems to work like post, so instead of updating previous data, it creates a new one with a unique ID.

Here is my code:

```
router.put("/update", (req, res, next) => {

  const formInput = new Form({
    // _id: '5e20275e2d0f182dd4ba320a',
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
  });
  Form.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: '5e20275e2d0f182dd4ba320a'}, formInput, {new: true}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    return res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Mongoose Schema

```
var formSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    // required: true
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    // required: true
  },
},
  {
  collection: 'formsInput'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', formSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new Form instance for updating, you can simply do

```
router.put("/update", (req, res, next) => {

  Form.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: '5e20275e2d0f182dd4ba320a'}, {...req.body}, {new: true}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    return res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `formInput` parameter to `findByIdAndUpdate` should be a plain object, not a `Form` instance:

```
const formInput = {
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
};
```